# DateTime::modify and DST switch

Tags: php, datetime

Using [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to add an hour across a DST boundary causes it to skip an hour.

e.g.

```
$d = new DateTime('2015-11-01 12:00:00 AM', new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver'));
$d->modify('+1 hour'); // 1 AM
$d->modify('+1 hour'); // 2 AM
$d->modify('+1 hour'); // 3 AM
```

I want to see "1 AM" twice (and *then* "2 AM") because time goes back an hour.

How can I get this behaviour?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65811

Answer (score 2):

It's [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65811). ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974388/datetimemodify-and-dst-switch#comment51858487_31974388))

To work around it, change the timezone to UTC and then back again.

```
$d = new DateTime('2015-11-01 12:00:00 AM', new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver'));

$tz = getTimezone();
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$d->modify('+1 hour'); 
$d->modify('+1 hour'); 
$d->modify('+1 hour'); 
$d->setTimezone($tz);
echo $d->format('d-M-Y g:ia'); // 01-Nov-2015 2:00am
```