# How to fix this very frustrating time bug in my time code?

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, strtotime

I have these two functions:

```
function time_is_older_than($timestamp, $time_string)
{
    if (strtotime($timestamp) < strtotime('-' . $time_string))
        return true;

    return false;
}

function time_is_younger_than($timestamp, $time_string)
{
    if (strtotime($timestamp) > strtotime('-' . $time_string))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

They enable me to do neat things like:

```
if (time_is_older_than($last_time_some_action_happened, '5 minutes'))
    do_it_again();
```

They normally **work**, *except* for **during one hour every six months**, when my timezone switches over to "summer time" or "winter time". This means that the clocks are increased or put back one hour at midnight (according to this timezone).

The PHP manual states this for `strtotime`:

> The Unix timestamp that this function returns does not contain information about time zones. In order to do calculations with date/time information, you should use the more capable DateTimeImmutable.

However, if I provide the exact same date/time string, with "+08:00" added in the end versus "+00:00", for example, I get different numbers of seconds returned. So `strtotime()` does understand timezones when it parses the provided time, even if the returned integer obviously doesn't contain this information. (Nor is it expected or required to by me.)

I've spent countless hours trying to debug this, testing countless things, and just sitting here thinking, but I can't figure out what exactly would make the code I have fail, specifically for one hour. And especially what about it I need to change. Setting the second parameter for `strtotime()` seems likely, but I just couldn't make it work correctly.

My hottest "lead" for quite some time was that the `strtotime('-' . $time_string)` part is ending up using a different timezone than the timestamp strings provided, but I do provide timezone data to it most of the time! An example of `$last_time_some_action_happened` might be something like `2020-10-28 02:22:41.123456+01`.

I set the timezone with `date_default_timezone_set()`.

I suspect that I only need to make some very minor change, but I've been experimenting so much and so long now, even taking rests in between, that my brain can no longer see this clearly. I bet the solution is something awfully simple.

Please don't tell me to use `DateTimeImmutable`. This would fundamentally change my entire structure and require me to do things very differently. Perhaps I *should*, and even *will*, at some point, but for now, I just wish to fix this rare but still very annoying bug in my existing code. (If it's possible at all, which I very much believe is the case.)

Comment: have you tried `date_default_timezone_set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the issue you are having:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');

// Daylight saving time 2020 in New Zealand began at 2:00am on Sunday, 27 September
$current = strtotime('2020-09-27 02:04:00');

$d1 = strtotime('2020-09-27 02:05:00', $current);
$d2 = strtotime('-5 minutes', $current);

var_dump($d1 > $d2); // false
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d1)); // 2020-09-27 03:05:00
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d2)); // 2020-09-27 03:59:00
```

This person looks to be having the same issue as you and may appear to be a bug.
[DateTime::modify and DST switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974388/datetimemodify-and-dst-switch)
The solution is to convert the dates to UTC then compare:

```
// Convert to UTC and compare
$d1 = new \DateTime('2020-09-27 02:05:00', new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));

$d2 = new \DateTime('2020-09-27 02:04:00', new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
$d2->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$d2->modify('-5 minutes');
$d2->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));

var_dump($d1 > $d2); // true
var_dump($d1->format(\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)); // 2020-09-27T03:05:00.000+13:00
var_dump($d2->format(\DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED)); // 2020-09-27T01:59:00.000+12:00
```

I've updated your functions:

```
function time_is_older_than($datetime, $time_string)
{
    $d1 = new \DateTime($datetime);
    $d1->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    
    $d2 = new \DateTime();
    $d2->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $d2->modify('-' . $time_string);
    
    return $d1 < $d2;
}

function time_is_younger_than($datetime, $time_string)
{
    $d1 = new \DateTime($datetime);
    $d1->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    
    $d2 = new \DateTime();
    $d2->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $d2->modify('-' . $time_string);
    
    return $d1 > $d2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it, and it appears to be working so far. (But then again, only time will tell...) It feels good that this was indeed a bug, and not just me having fundamentally misunderstood something, but the existence of said bug also bugs me (no pun intended). It seems like there is always some "crazy workaround" that has to be performed for anything to truly work properly, which bothers me. By the way, since the code is nearly identical for both functions, can one of them just "do the reverse of the other"?

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider a solution:
In the timestamp string（like Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200）, add a timezone tag which specify timezone without difference of daylight saving time.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a timezone tag? And then the `strtotime('-' . $time_string)` will also have to be changed somehow... I don't get what you mean at all. Sorry.